# how to hide or delete the button on top_right statusBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c

**when i use universal links in weixin, the domain appear on the top_right of statusbar, how to hide or delete the button?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9KDf.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

That's a new feature in iOS 9. I don't think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is used for jumping from one app to another. and Its generate every time when you use [UIApplication openURL:]. Apple not give rights to remove this features to developer. But in future, Apple publicly give access to edit or delete this feature because there are many case in this feature is not suitable.